# Log names of called methods in React class component with ES6 Proxy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-proxy

I have a React class component with many methods. I would like to inspect the order, in which these methods are called. Although it is possible to add console.log into each method like this:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log("constructor")
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log('handleClick');
  }
  
  componentDidMount() { 
    console.log('componentDidMount');
  }
  
  render() {
    console.log('render');
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>button</button>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

I would rather make a reusable solution. So far I made an interceptor that would use ES6 Proxy on a class instance. It is logging in console each called method of instance of simple (not React) class.

```js
class Calculation {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 5;
    this.b = 5;
  }

  calcSum() {
    return this.a + this.b;
  }

  getResult() {
    this.calcSum();
  }
}

const calc = new Calculation();

function interceptMethodCalls(obj) {
  return new Proxy(obj, {
    get(target, prop) {
      if (typeof target[prop] === 'function') {
        return new Proxy(target[prop], {
          apply: (target, thisArg, argumentsList) => {
            console.log(prop);
            return Reflect.apply(target, thisArg, argumentsList);
          },
        });
      } else {
        return Reflect.get(target, prop);
      }
    },
  });
}

const interceptedObj = interceptMethodCalls(calc);

interceptedObj.getResult()
```

When I try to intercept React component methods it is failing:

```js
function interceptMethodCalls(obj) {
  return new Proxy(obj, {
    get(target, prop) {
      if (typeof target[prop] === 'function') {
        return new Proxy(target[prop], {
          apply: (target, thisArg, argumentsList) => {
            console.log(prop);
            return Reflect.apply(target, thisArg, argumentsList);
          },
        });
      } else {
        return Reflect.get(target, prop);
      }
    },
  });
}


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleClick() {
    // handle click
  }
  
  componentDidMount() { 
    // after mount
  }
  
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>button</button>;
  }
}



let interceptedObj = interceptMethodCalls(<App/>);

ReactDOM.render(interceptedObj, document.getElementById("container"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

How can I make it log the name of each called method in React class component? If I write decorator based on Proxy, that could be useful in researching class components

Comment: No, don't use a proxy here. You want to use a decorator instead that simply wraps the methods existing on the class.

Comment: If you do a `console.log(<App/>)` (or log the `obj` that is passed to `interceptMethodCalls`) you'll see what's going wrong.